# initialization of static member of template class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, gcc, clang

Consider the following:

```
template<class T>
struct A
{
  struct B
  {} static const b;
};

// case 1
template<class T>
typename A<T>::B const A<T>::b;

// case 2
template<class T>
typename A<T>::B const A<T>::b{};

int main()
{
  A<int> a;
  a.b;
  return 0;
}
```

**case1:**

gcc 5.2 passes
msvc 2015 update 1 passes
clang 3.7 error:

```
default initialization of an object of const type 'const typename A<int>::B' without a user-provided default constructor
```

**case2:**

gcc 5.2 passes
clang 3.7 passes:
msvc 2015 update 1 error:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<end Parse>'
```

Which compiler is right / wrong in each case?

Comment: Interesting question; I tried it on my pc with VS2015 and I am getting the same results. Case 1 Works, and Case 2 is giving the same compiler error.

Comment: Case 1 is [CWG 253](http://wg21.link/cwg253). Case 2 is MSVC bug (`= {}` seems to work with MSVC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (8.5 Initializers)

7. ...If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a
   **user-provided default constructor**.

So clang correctly reports the diagnostoc message.

As for the second case then it seems the used MS compiler does not support the list initialization or has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
typename A<T>::B
```

is type

```
A<T>::
```

is scope

```
const A<T>::
```

is it a const scope?

It should be:

```
const typename A<T>::B A<T>::b;
```

Comment: I thought `const int` and `int const` are the same. Your suggestion gives the same compilation errors.

Comment: For me it compiler perfectly, it has to be compiler bug (cygwin g++ 4.9.3)